# Automapper uri to string convention

Tags: automapper

Using Automapper, what is the best way to setup a global convention such that all `System.Uri` properties are converted to a string that represents the `AbsoluteUri` property?

Ideally, I'd like to have a null System.Uri resolve to a value of `String.Empty` rather than `null`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setup the map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<System.Uri, string>().ConvertUsing<UriToStringConverter>();
```

Create the TypeConverter class:

```
public class UriToStringConverter : ITypeConverter<System.Uri, string>
{
    public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
         if (context.SourceValue == null)
         {
            return String.Empty;
         }

         return ((System.Uri)context.SourceValue).AbsoluteUri;
    }
}
```